# Passing an argument from python script to Word Macro VBA (pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.')

Tags: python, vba, ms-word, pywin32, comtypes

I have a Word Macro VBA script that inserts a docx file in a word document:

```
Public Sub Macro(path As String)
Selection.InsertFile FileName:=path, Range:="", ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=True, Attachment:= False

ActiveDocument.Close_ SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges, _ OriginalFormat:=wdOriginalDocumentFormat

Aplication.Quit SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
```

I would like to create a python script that calls the Macro and pass as an argument the path of the file which will be inserted in the VBA script.

```
import win32com.client as win32

word = win32.DispatchEx('Word.Application')
word.Visible = True

doc = word.Documents.Open(r'path to file .docx')
   
word.Application.Run("Complete.Macro.Name", "path_to_file_docx")
```

But I am getting  the following error:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352567), None)
```

I read that if the Sub receives an argument the VBA is not a Macro anymore. Does anyone know how to overcome this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57065202/run-a-word-vba-macro-with-python  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717635/call-a-macro-with-parameters-python-win32com-api

Comment: Already tried this, but it is not working for a Word Macro.

Comment: " I am getting an error" is not a useful description of what happens when you run your code.

Comment: Sorry for that, already fixed

Comment: Does `Complete.Macro.Name` include the file name?

Comment: No, just the macro name, such as "Normal.NewMacros.MergeMacro", which "MergeMacro" is the name of the Sub.

Comment: Running just "MergeMacro" I get the same error as before

Comment: Is the macro Public?

Comment: Just added "Public", but I am getting the same pywintypes.com_error.

Comment: Sorry not a Python user so can't test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
import sys
import pywintypes

try:
    ...
except pywintypes.com_error:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Seems to solve the problem.